# PHP - static trait method implementation in class

Tags: php, traits

I've implemented a trait that will be used as an helper to share some common functions between some classes. The problem is that I will get an error output from console when I try to execute the code.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found

All the classes and the trait are on the same file. Here is how I've implemented it. What's wrong?

```
trait xHelpers{

  static function _files(array $__files_list){

       $_filelist = array();

       foreach ($__files_list as $_file) {
           for($i = 0; $i < count($_file); $i++){
             $_filelist[] = $_file[$i];
           }
       }
       return array_filter($_filelist);
  }

  static function patch_(array $_filename, array $patterns, array $replace){

      foreach($_filename as $file){
          $_file = file_get_contents($file);
          file_put_contents($file, str_replace($patterns, $replace, $_file));
      }
      return true;
  }

}

class MyClass{

    use xHelpers;

    public static function remove_(array $_filename, $patterns, $replace){
        foreach ($_filename as $_file) {
            $_replace = preg_replace("/$patterns/", $replace, $_file);
            rename($_file, $_replace);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

if(MyClass::_files($array)) goto b;
```

> All the code are on the same file. So this issue can't be related to
>   class autoloading.

Comment: Your autoloader cannot find your class. Got nothing to do with traits.

Comment: I don't use an autoloader. If you read the post, I wrote that all the code is on a single page. I have the script code that call the class and the class plus the trait on the same file.

Comment: Is your class on top of the file after the `<?php`tag ?

Comment: The code you've got here works as it is though... sort of, the output isn't what I expected but it runs. I just copied it into an empty PHP file and replaced `if(MyClass::_files($array)) goto b;` with `if($a = MyClass::_files(scandir(__DIR__))) print_r($a);` for debugging purposes.

Comment: @CD001 for a strange behavior, I've moved the code on top of the file after the `<?php` open tag and the issue was solved.